# Pluggability in a functional paradigm

Tags: f#, functional-programming

What is the proper functional way to handle pluggability in projects?  I am working on a new opensource project in F# and can not seem to get the object oriented idea of plugins and interfaces out of my mind.  Things I would like to be able to swap out are loggers, datastoring, and authentication.

I have been searching quite a bit for an answer to this and havent come up with much except for this: 
http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/12/extensibility-in-functional-programming.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to this question would be different for different functional languages. F# is not purely functional - it takes the best from functional, imperative and also object-oriented worlds.

For things like logging and authentication, the most pragmatic approach would be to use interfaces (in F#, it is perfectly fine to use interfaces, but people do not generally use inheritance and prefer composition instead).

A simple interface makes sense when you have multiple different functions that you can invoke:

```
 type IAuthentication =
   abstract Authenticate : string * string -> bool
   abstract ResetPassword : string * string -> void
```

You can use [object expressions](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/object-expressions/), which is a really nice way to implement interfaces in F#.
If you have just a single function (like logging a message), then you can parameterize your code by a function (which is like an interface with just a single method):

```
 type Logger = string -> unit
```

For things like authentication and logging (that probably do not change while the application is running), you can use a global mutable value. Although if you want to synchronize requests from multiple threads and there is some mutable state, it might be a good idea to write an [F# agent](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/139804/an-introduction-to-f-agents/#1).